# get list of followings/followers of google plus from google id in php

Tags: php, google-api

we are developing an app where we are providing google signin and we want to implement the feature that if particular user's google connections also installed the app, we need to display in one section. so we are getting particular user's google id and google token while google signin. Now we want to get list of his connections from his google id or google token

we have seen this link `https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people` but it will be useful when we are making website out of it. We are making an Android app so we require to fetch list of connections from the user's google id or google token

Is it possible? if yes, please help us

Thanks in advance!